Understanding the Relationship Between Closed Submodules and Pure Submodules of Finitely Generated Torsion-Free Modules Over an Integral Domain
Let $R$ be an integral domain, and let $M$ be a finitely generated and torsion-free $R$-module.
In $(4.7)$ on the page 477 of the paper FINITISTIC DIMENSION AND A HOMOLOGICAL GENERALIZATION OF SEMI-PRIMARY RINGS, it is stated that the closed submodules of $M$ are precisely the pure submodules of $M$. I am uncertain about the underlying reason. Could someone kindly provide an explanation?
Here is the supplementary information on closed submodules: $N$ is a closed submodule of $M$ if and only if $M/N$ is a torsionless module.
